# Double accept on server side socket

Tags: c++, sockets, server

I am building a server using Sockets on Linux, and I'm having a weird problem: if I try to send a request via my browser (Chrome), my code will create two sockets for communication using accept. Here's the code that accepts a connection:

```
server->poll();

if (server->canRead(server))
{
  cout << "Connection!" << endl;
  newSocket = server->accept(poolSize);
}
```

And here are the functions used (which are part of a wrapper I wrote for the C socket library).

```
    int ServerSocket::poll(int timeout)
{
  int rc = ::poll(this->descriptors, this->maxDescriptors, timeout);

  if(rc == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Error: ") + strerror(errno));

  return rc;
}

bool ServerSocket::canRead(Socket *socket)
{
  if(socket == NULL)
    throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("Error: null socket!"));

  for (int i = 0; i < this->maxDescriptors; i++)
  {
    if (socket->socketDescriptor == this->descriptors[i].fd)
    {
      if (this->descriptors[i].revents & POLLIN)
        return true;

      break;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

ClientSocket* ServerSocket::accept(const int poolSize)
{
  socklen_t endpointSize = sizeof(this->endpoint);

  int newDescriptor = ::accept(this->socketDescriptor,
                              (struct sockaddr *)&endpoint, &endpointSize);

  if(newDescriptor == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Error in accept: ") + strerror(errno));

  ClientSocket *newSocket = NULL;

  try
  {
    newSocket = new ClientSocket(newDescriptor, this->port, poolSize);
  }
  catch (std::exception e)
  {
    std::cout << "Allocation error!" << endl;
    throw e;
  }

  return newSocket;
}
```

If I compile and run this code, my output is:

```
Connection!
Connection!
```

I've used both telnet and netcat to analyse the requisition made by the browser, and it shows no anomaly. I've also sent requests manually via telnet and netcat, and the server works just fine, no duplicate connections. What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Have tcpdump captured while you do the test. See if you see two connect requests coming in.

Comment: Because your browser connected twice. Why did it do that? I don't know. Try Wireshark, or make your server print the requests.

Comment: I've set it up so that the server would print out the requests, and turns out that (as the URL was saved by the browser) just by scrolling down to the URL sends a request of some sort, and when I hit enter, it sends another one. So there is the reason...

Comment: This is **not** [tag:c]

Comment: @Eregrith, I've written a wrapper for the C socket functions, so I believe it is related.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta not for the purpose of your question I think.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a verification and deny similar requests from the same host within X seconds of one another. Is that a good practice, or is there a better way?

Comment: You don't really need that.  Especially if the web browser is the client.  It may need to send multiple requests very quickly, depending on the content that you are sending to it.